# OpenAm (as IdP): SSO login returning NoAuthnContext (unable to login with SSO)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, openam

Below is the metadata file for IdP at OpenAm

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EntityDescriptor entityID="http://myidp.com/openam" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <KeyDescriptor use="signing">
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
MIICQD.....0Y0Q==
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </KeyDescriptor>
        <ArtifactResolutionService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/ArtifactResolver/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPSloRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPSloPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPSloSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPMniRedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp" ResponseLocation="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPMniPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <ManageNameIDService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/IDPMniSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:WindowsDomainQualifiedName</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:kerberos</NameIDFormat>
        <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</NameIDFormat>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/SSORedirect/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/SSOPOST/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/SSOSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <NameIDMappingService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/NIMSoap/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <AssertionIDRequestService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/AIDReqSoap/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
        <AssertionIDRequestService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:URI" Location="http://myidp.com/openam/AIDReqUri/IDPRole/metaAlias/idp"/>
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

SP is located at : http://mysp.com/

SP's Auth url where SAML response can be posted is at : http://mysp.com/login

The following request works for SSO Login: http://myidp.com/openam/idpssoinit?metaAlias=%2Fidp&spEntityID=mysp.com&binding=urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Abindings%3AHTTP-POST&RelayState=http%3A%2F%2Fmysp.com
But I believe this is OpenAm specific, not SAML's standard way to authenticate.

When I post SAML Request to http://myidp.com/openam/SSOPOST/metaAlias/idp it returns the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<samlp:Response ID="s2ffea3d194a0d2587fd0cfc9cc8c57fa4a9414159" InResponseTo="_ad466c99-c8b6-4fbf-96c9-922dffc3ea22" IssueInstant="2013-05-03T07:22:34Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    http://myidp.com/openam
  </saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:Status xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:NoAuthnContext" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      </samlp:StatusCode>
    </samlp:StatusCode>
  </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

SAML request I posted is base 64 encoded version of the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://mysp.com/login" ID="_ad466c99-c8b6-4fbf-96c9-922dffc3ea22" IssueInstant="2013-05-03T12:35:42" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    mysp.com
  </saml:Issuer>
  <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
  <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact"/>
  <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
  </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Since Its working in first case, most probably it should be some issue with SAML request. Is there any parameter which is present is first request but not in 2nd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthnContextClassRef should be inside RequestedAuthnContext. Your request should look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://mysp.com/login" ID="_ad466c99-c8b6-4fbf-96c9-922dffc3ea22" IssueInstant="2013-05-03T12:35:42" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        mysp.com
    </saml:Issuer>    
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Comment: Previous error is gone. But OpenAm returns "HTTP ERROR 500
Problem accessing /openam/saml2/jsp/saml2error.jsp. Reason: Unable to do Single Sign On or Federation" and does not redirect back to SP's url

Comment: Well, this is a new probably not related. I would recommend locking in the OpenAM log files to find the reason for this problem

Comment: I changed NameIdPolicy from unspecified to transient and it worked! Although I would like to know the reason for that. so you may want to edit the answer.

Comment: Its hard to know without the log entry. If you can it it will problably giva a hint

Comment: It worked so probably I will see the log entry later to find the reason!

Comment: The right NameID Format is "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified". Note the "1.1" in the urn.